# What is the regex to find a single line of text preceding a question mark?

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, I would just like to match all instances of text between line breaks, preceding a question mark, such as:

`It would not match this text.`

`How would I match this text?`

I am trying to automatically highlight all questions onblur of a textarea.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: can you put a sample and also desired output?

Comment: In running text in HTML, line breaks that are introduced by the browser to fit content into a box (like the content in your question) aren't "real".  They're not present in the DOM, and the browser doesn't trouble itself with telling you what the rendered running text looks like. Thus, the very concept of a "line" is awfully hard to work with in the browser context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
^.*\?$
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/gX0yT3/1)

---

`^` and `$` anchor to the beginning and end of the string. `.*` matches 0+ characters (except newlines). `\?` matches a question mark just before the end of the string. In Javascript, use [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
var regex = /^.*\?$/gm;

console.log('It would not match this text.'.match(regex));
console.log('How would I match this text?'.match(regex));
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: First, you should mention that this only works in `multiline mode` and second your regex fails, if there is another text after the question. I know that this has not been stated by the op, but should be considered or at least mentioned. http://regex101.com/r/rU0mM4/1

Comment: @dognose, thanks, I should have the `m` modifier (and `g`). I don't think I need to do anything else, since OP asked *"match all instances of text* ***between line breaks,*** *preceding a question mark."*

Comment: @Sam you're right. your post *answers the question*.