# How do I find all sentences with a question mark at the end in a a text file

Tags: regex, notepad++

how do I find all sentences with a question mark at the end? Specifically the character immediately after `.` and up to and including the `?`. **Note:** there will be various characters inbetween that I would like to capture also e.g. \n...etc

This link helps
[What is the regex to find a single line of text preceding a question mark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433624/what-is-the-regex-to-find-a-single-line-of-text-preceding-a-question-mark)

example text:

```
now"? She said, "I feel great". Then I said to her, "All right, would 
you mind leaving the room for a minute or two? This is part of the 
exercise". So she did. While she was away, I said to the others in the 
therapy group, "I am still the provincial superior, O.K.?
```

What i have got is this

`\.*.*\?`

which will help me find 1, 2, 3, in the above sample text, [REGEX HERE](https://regex101.com/r/mIxVVl/1)

`now"?` She said, "I feel great". Then I said to her, "All right, would 
`you mind leaving the room for a minute or two?` This is part of the 
exercise". So she did. While she was away, I said to the others in the 
`therapy group, "I am still the provincial superior, O.K.?`

But what i want is to find is everything between . and ?

So for example I would like to find the belw(which would have a \n in it also) 
`While she was away, I said to the others in the 
therapy group, "I am still the provincial superior, O.K.?`

**Note:**
Just thinking there I might have to format the text first so that ever line ends with a `.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a character set excluding periods and question marks, with an alternation of a period that isn't followed by a space. Avoid matching a space as the start of a sentence by first matching a non-space, non-period:

```
[^\s.](?:[^?.]|\.(?! ))*\?
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mIxVVl/5

Comment: Maybe small improvement - use [A-Z] instead of [^\s.] in your regex, since every sentence should start with a capital letter. This will get rid of the now"? match in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex which also handles quotation marks:

All sentences

```
(?<=[.?!]\s)[A-Z][^"]*("[^"]+")?[^".?!]*[?.!]
```

All sentences ending in question mark

```
(?<=[.?!]\s)[A-Z][^"]*("[^"]+")?[^".?!]*[?]
```

And this looks inside a quoted text:

```
(?<=")[A-Z][^"]*[?]
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/IcMr4G/1).

In order to be correct, all text between quotation marks (even several sentences) is to be treated as one word.

If analysis of text within quotation marks is to be done, a new question needs to be asked ;)

Notes:

1. Real texts can bring all kinds of unusual constructs, so regexes will not always catch everything.
2. `"Something is here.` is not an actual sentence - notice the missing closing quotation mark.

Comment: This does not match a sentence at the beginning of a string.

Comment: Not that it is a good answer, but yours does not either :) Unless you consider `now"?` a sentence.

Comment: My answer matches a sentence at the beginning of a string. Whether or not quotation marks are matched is not within the scope of the OP's question.

Comment: `is not within the scope of the OP's question`: that is exactly what i said too: `If analysis of text within quotation marks is to be done, a new question needs to be asked`

Comment: Exactly. So my answer not dealing with matching quotation marks is not relevant to the question. Matching the very first sentence at the beginning of a string, on the other hand, is relevant to the OP's requirements.

Comment: `Matching the very first sentence at the beginning of a string` - to test it, just remove the fragment `now"?` (it is not a sentence by any definition of the word) and retest your regex.